# How to read task using EWSJavaAPI?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi, microsoft-exchange

I am using an EWSJavaAPI for creating task in Exchange Server but i am not getting any reference to fetch task using the same api.
Below is my code add task:

```
    Task t=new Task(service);
    t.setSubject("Task to test in JAVA");
    t.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Test body from JAVA"));
    t.setStartDate(startTime);
    t.setDueDate(endTime);
    t.save();
```

And i tried below code to fetch task but this is not working :

```
    //Create the extended property definition.
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition taskCompleteProp = new 
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x0000811C, 
    MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
    //Create the search filter.
    SearchFilter.IsEqualTo filter = new 
    SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(taskCompleteProp, false);                    
    //Get the tasks.
    FindItemsResults<Item> tasks = 
    service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, filter, new ItemView(50));

    for(Item task:tasks){
        System.out.println(task.getSubject());
        System.out.println(task.getBody());// getting error at this line
        System.out.println(task.getReminderMinutesBeforeStart());
        System.out.println(task.getReminderDueBy());
        System.out.println("=======================");

    }
```

error at task.getBody();
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceObjectPropertyException: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertyBag.getPropertyValueOrException(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertyBag.getObjectFromPropertyDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item.getBody(Unknown Source)
    at MSExchangeEmailService.readTask(MSExchangeEmailService.java:146)
    at MSExchangeEmailService.main(MSExchangeEmailService.java:224)

Please help, is this right approach to fetch task??

Comment: for(Item task:tasks){
      task.load();//added this line 
      System.out.println(task.getSubject());
      System.out.println(task.getBody());  
     } After adding task.load() i am able to get body but now i want to get task startdate and duedate .How to get this

Comment: Are you setting `startdate` and `duedate` to some value earlier in your code? E.G `task.StartDate = DateTime.Now;`. if yes, then you can just do  `System.out.println(task.StartDate);`

Comment: No i am not creating any task just reading reading task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the Task first.

Add `task.load()` before your `for` loop.

Comment: task.load() i did as written in code, but not able to get startdate and due date.

Comment: OK please mark this as the answer as it answers your original question. I see you have created a new question for your new issue so that should be kept separate from this question.